# .NET msi installer version

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, deployment, windows-installer, setup-project

How can you set up the version of the MSI installer that was created via Setup Project in Visual Studio 2008?

I entered a value in the "Version" Property of the Deployment Project, but I'm not sure where I can see it when I view the properties of the actual MSI file in Windows Explorer.

The description for the "Version" Property in Visual Studio says "Specifies the version number of an installer, merge module, or .cab file".

The "File version" and "Product version" Windows Explorer Columns of the MSI file are both empty.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know that you can view the ProductVersion of an MSI via Windows Explorer. You might want to check out [ORCA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which lets you view and edit a MSI file. Alternatively, you might try the following [SO QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359974/how-to-include-version-number-in-vs-setup-project-output-filename) regarding renaming a MSI to include the ProductVersion, something like MyInstaller1.00.00.msi.

Comment: Thank you, Tim.  I'll check these out!