# How to query a msi primary output to get the assembly version?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-installer, post-build-event

What I want is get the version that is on the primary output keyoutput properties and rename it from myapp.msi to myapp-v1.0.15.45.msi

[image]

in-vs-setup-project-output-filename
I know how to query the msi by using the code I found in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359974/how-to-include-version-number-in-vs-setup-project-output-filename), here is the code. How can I do want I want using a similar code snippet?

```
 static string GetMsiProperty(string msiFile, string property)
    {
        string retVal = string.Empty;

        // Create an Installer instance  
        Type classType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("WindowsInstaller.Installer");
        Object installerObj = Activator.CreateInstance(classType);
        Installer installer = installerObj as Installer;

        // Open the msi file for reading  
        // 0 - Read, 1 - Read/Write  
        Database database = installer.OpenDatabase(msiFile, 0);

        // Fetch the requested property  
        string sql = String.Format("SELECT Value FROM Property WHERE Property='{0}'", property);
        View view = database.OpenView(sql);
        view.Execute(null);

        // Read in the fetched record  
        Record record = view.Fetch();

        while (record != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(record.get_StringData(0) + '=' + record.get_StringData(1) + '=' + record.get_StringData(2) + '=' + record.get_StringData(3));
            record = view.Fetch();
        }
        view.Close();
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(view);
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(database);

        return retVal;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you've tried and if you've run that code at all, but the shortest answer is that you call that code and ask for the ProductVersion property.

[ProductVersion property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370859(v=vs.85).aspx)