# In .net, how do I use the Version number from the Deployment Project Properties?

Tags: c#, .net, version

In .net, how do I access the Version number from the Deployment Project Properties?

I know about the assembly version number but wanted to just change the version number in one place.

Comment: Incomplete and unclear. When do you want to change it?  Provide steps and example values.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this.  I did research this and found nothing that explained how can I read the version number in Deployment Project Properties with a c# program?

Comment: Check [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359974/how-to-include-version-number-in-vs-setup-project-output-filename)

Comment: After further reading, I now understand (partially anyway) that the version number in the Assemblyinfo file is the application version, while the version in the Deployment Project properties is the installer version.  The former is accessible as Application.ProductVersion and can easily be displayed in the app.  The latter shows up in add/remove programs, but one has to jump through hoops to use it in a program.  I'll just keep these two versions the same.